# How to run an AppleScript when Mac starts charging in "AC Power"?

Tags: applescript, battery, automator, charging, plist

I have an AppleScript that has to run when my Mac switches to AC Power and it has to run at regular intervals till it switches back to Battery Power.

I have a sample `plist` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>show-battery-warning</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What should I change or add here?
I searched for this in a lot of places. But cannot find anything convincing

Or is there any way to totally avoid this and use the **Automator** app instead?

**PS:** My main objective is to display a notification when the battery charge exceeds 90% when charging.

Comment: Welcome to **Ask Different**! What version of **macOS** are your running? You said "I have a sample `plist` file.", and then said "What should I change or add here? I searched for this in a lot of places. But cannot find anything convincing", but do you even know what to do with the **plist** _file_, where it should go and how to enable it, etc? What does your **AppleScript** _code_ look like? For more help with the  **plist** _file_ have a look at the _manual pages_ for `launchd.plist`, `launchctl` and `launchd`.

Comment: You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: You don’t want to “totally avoid this” and “use the Automator app instead”.  An Automator-based solution certainly wouldn’t be a better one, and in many circumstances, will probably be a worse one.

Comment: @user3439894, I'm getting started with the idea of using AppleScript to perform several tasks. I heard about the term `plist` only a few hours back. Although I understood that it is a form of XML, I don't know much about it. As of now, I'm trying to figure out if this approach would even work. If this wouldn't work I have to think about some other method.

Comment: The version of macOS I'm using is macOS 11.1 (Big Sur)

Comment: I gave this problem some thought as well.  I think whatever your solution ends up using to retrieve the battery power status, you chose the right direction with using a plist (property list), which is loaded into `launchd` (the Daemon that regulates things on an interval). The question of how to determine when the power source changes is something that conventionally, one would write a script to listen for the notification behind the scenes, but you need to use a language that can use Core Foundation data types; AppleScript is not one of them.

Comment: The last resort method would do interval checks for a visible element on screen that AppleScript could probably retrieve details for. In Catalina, that could be the battery icon that indicates it's not plugged in. The downside is it won't know until the next check whether the state has changed, unlike the previous method that would know immediately. You may be able to use JXA (AppleScript written in JavaScript), but not sure what the state of it is in Big Sur.